# Save postfix email copy in database

Tags: mysql, linux, email, postfix-mta

I currently have a mail and webserver for a customer.
I am using `postfix` as mail server to relay email adresses to the correct users. for example, john.doe@mydomain.com is relayed to john.doe@gmail.com.

Now I would like to be able to display the mails on the website, but also keep sending them to the users. So, I was wondering if there is an option to send a copy of the mail to a mysql database?

This is my current **main.cf**:

```
# Settings
myhostname = mydomain.com

# Spam adressen
#smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access

# KLJ Waregem aliasses
virtual_alias_domains = mydomain.com
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-mydomain.cf

# Mails via Mandrill
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_use_tls = yes
relayhost = [smtp.mandrillapp.com]

alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases

# Spam quarantine via Amavis-New
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024

# More spam protection
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_path = smtpd
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.cert
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.key

readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
```

And my **master.cf**:

```
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
pickup    fifo  n       -       -       60      1       pickup -o content_filter= -o receive_override_options=no_header_$
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     fifo  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -       n       n       -       2       pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}

spamassassin unix -     n       n       -       -       pipe
        user=spamd argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -e
        /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}

smtp-amavis     unix    -       -       -       -       2       smtp
        -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200
        -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
        -o disable_dns_lookups=yes
        -o max_use=20

127.0.0.1:10025 inet    n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
        -o content_filter=
        -o local_recipient_maps=
        -o relay_recipient_maps=
        -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
        -o smtpd_delay_reject=no
        -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
        -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
        -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
        -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
        -o smtpd_data_restrictions=reject_unauth_pipelining
        -o smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions=
        -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
        -o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0
        -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001
        -o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000
        -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=0
        -o smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit=0
        -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks
```

Thanks for the help,
Jerodev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postfix can't put messages into a database by itself. However, it has a [pipe](http://www.postfix.org/pipe.8.html) delivery method, which runs a custom command once for every incoming message. You need to write a program which would put the message into the database.

Then, add a line to `master.cf` describing your new delivery method. The file you provided has a few example definitions. You'll have to write one tailored for your program.

Then, use `always_bcc` option in `main.cf` to have a copy of every incoming message sent to a special local address, and configure Postfix to have messages sent to that address delivered using your newly configured delivery method. [This page](http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html) documents how delivery method selection is performed.

Comment: Is there any way I can send the bcc to a folder on the server and let a cronjob check the folder every x minutes?

Comment: Postfix has a [local](http://www.postfix.org/local.8.html) delivery agent which can store incoming mail in a mailbox file. It puts all messages into the same file which you would have to parse. You still need a program to put messages into a database. Delivering directly to a program is better because messages are processed in real time. Also, when using a file, you would have to lock it appropriately because otherwise you would have a data race.

Comment: So, now I made a new hook in my `master.cf`: `save_php unix - n n - - pipe flags=F user=www-data argv=/var/www/mysite/Scripts/mail/postfixReceive.php ${sender} ${size} ${recipient}`.

But how do I send the mails to this hook? I have tried adding it to the pickup using `content_filter`, but that didn't work.

When I add the `content_filter` to smtp, it works, but the mail is no longer forwarded to the receiver

Comment: @Jerodev You need to set your hook as a transport, not as a filter. For example, if you don't already use `local_transport`, set `local_transport = save_php` in `main.cf`, then set `always_bcc = something@localhost` (assuming that you didn't change `mydestination`). Then a copy of every message would be sent to `something@localhost`, and every message sent to `localhost` would be fed into your script.

Comment: Thank you, I got it to work using your help, [this article](http://blog.thecodingmachine.com/content/triggering-php-script-when-your-postfix-server-receives-mail), and a lot of hard thinking. :p

You are a life saver! :D

Comment: above article link may changed to https://thecodingmachine.io/triggering-a-php-script-when-your-postfix-server-receives-a-mail